# Is there any way to set fixed colors for the WaterfallDataSeries3D?

Tags: c#, xaml, scichart

I've already set the *GradientStops*, but after I remove the current *RenderableSeries* and then add a new *WaterfallRenderableSeries3D*. It looks totally diffrent.

The graph with the right colors:
[image: picture provided by using SciChart]

The graph with the wrong colors:
[image: picture provided by using SciChart]

```
<s3D:GradientColorPalette x:Key="GradientColorPalette" IsStepped="False">
    <s3D:GradientColorPalette.GradientStops>
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Red"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="0.25" Color="Orange"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Yellow"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="0.75" Color="Green"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="DarkGreen"/>
    </s3D:GradientColorPalette.GradientStops>
</s3D:GradientColorPalette>
```

I would like to use the same *GradientColorPalette* on every instance/*RenderableSeries*. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: So is it one GradientColorPalette instance on many WaterfallRenderableSeries3D? If so that might be cause of the issue. Maybe try first to set a new GradientColorPalette on each WaterfallRenderableSeries3D? If that works you can try setting it once in style using x:Shared = false